# Resizing array of vector

Tags: c++

```
class graph
{
    vector<int > a[];
    int nodes,edges;

public:
    graph(int n,int m)
    {
        nodes=n;edges=m;
        a = new vector<int> [n];
    }
};
```

This is a snippet from my code. How do I resize the `array` of `vector<int>`? I tried to dynamically assign the size. But its giving error.

Comment: vector<vector<int>> is much better

Comment: The declaration `vector<int > a[];` is not valid C++.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Actually it is in some context, but in this case it declares a variable of *"an incomplete object type"*.

Comment: @Holt: It's good to be aware of contexts, but in your answer you write "you cannot declare object of incomplete type", which isn't sufficiently context-qualified for the most pedantic, I think. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I am not aware of context where it is allowed to define object with incomplete type - Are there any? The goal of my note was to point out that this is not a valid declaration in this context (there may be context where it is, but I am not going to list them, it would be useless here... ) and to explain why it compiles on gcc (and thus why it raises an error when assigning from `new ...`).

Comment: You can declare an unsized array at namespace scope. That's necessary to link to one in another translation unit. It's good that you're raising the issue of such contexts without even being aware of one, heh. First time I've seen that. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I am aware of contexts where `T x[]` is valid. What I understood from your comment (maybe I was wrong) was that there were contexts in which you can declare variable of incomplete type. Since as you pointed out `extern int a[];` is valid but `a` has incomplete type (afaik), such contexts exist, meaning that I probably missed something in the standard. (BTW, I'm sorry if my previous comments seemed snobbish, there weren't mean too, my english is just not that great ;) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` instead of a "raw" array of `std::vector<...>` and then use `.resize()`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
a.resize(n);
```

This will save you from having to write a lots of boilerplate code (custom destructor, copy-constructor, ...), and will be much less error prone than your actual code.

---

The actual problem in your code is that `vector<int> a[]` should not be valid in this context: it declares a variable `a` of *"derived-declarator-type-list array of unknown bound of int”*, which is *"an incomplete object type"*, and you cannot declare object of incomplete type. On gcc, if you add `-pedantic`, you will get a warning:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'a' [-Wpedantic]

But without `-pedantic`, it declares a `std::vector<int> a[0]`, which cannot be assigned a `std::vector<int> *` and it is why you get an error when assigning `new std::vector<int> [n]`.